# VB Dictionary with same key more than once

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, for-loop, dictionary

Is it possible for a  dictionary to have the same key more than once?  I've looked around quite a bit and the answer seems to be YesNo.  I'm reading in cc numbers from a csv file and adding them to a dictionary.  Most posts that say no generally indicate that adding a key more than once throws an exception.  This would have to be wrong because I haven't encountered this problem.
Basically I have this dictionary

```
Dim allCalls As New Dictionary(Of String, Array)
```

and I'm populating it like this

```
 Dim Path As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Calls.txt"
    Dim reader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(Path)
    Dim parts() As String
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path)

    Array.Sort(lines)
    For x As Integer = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
        parts = lines(x).Split(CChar(","))
        Dim data(1) As String
        data(0) = parts(2)
        data(1) = parts(5)
        allCalls.Add(parts(1), data)
    Next

    reader.Close()
```

This part is working just fine, but as far as if I'm overwriting my old data when I add the same key I couldn't tell you.  However it seems counterintuitive to me that it wouldn't cause some sort of problem.  Basically my goal is to be able to search this thing for a key and get all the array data back which I can't figure out how to do.  I don't even really know if it is still in there so any help with how to work with these things would be great.

Comment: There does not seem to be built-in facility for this. What you can do is to make a dictionary that has a List as the type for its value. Then, when adding to the dictionary you need to check for existence of the key and add the value to the list that keeps all the values of the same key.

Comment: set a break on `reader.Close()`, then hold the mouse over `allCalls` you will be able to look at what is in there.  Dictionary keys are/must be unique otherwise there would be no  way to get the right data back. Use `allCall.ContainsKey` to test if a key exists already. `allCalls(key) = newData` will replace the data associated with that key.

Comment: If you're using at least .NET 3.5 you can use the [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class.

Comment: The answer is NoNo.  Having a unique value in the first column of a CSV file is not unusual.  It is commonly something like an order ID.

Comment: If you talking about `Dictionary<Tkey, Tvalue)`, You can NOT ever have 2 same keys. As soon as you will try to add second key, Exception will occur, something like, "Key already exists"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up using a Dictionary of ArrayList and just adding the arrays to that.  You devinitely can't store on the same key more than once, but checking if it exists and adding to the arraylist works well

Answer (score 0):

If you're using at least .NET 3.5 you can use the [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class.

> A `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` resembles a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The
>   difference is that a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` maps keys to single
>   values, whereas a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` maps keys to collections of
>   values.

Note

**There is no public constructor** to create a new instance of a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>`. Additionally, `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` objects are immutable, that is, you cannot add or remove elements or keys from a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` object after it has been created.

But you can use [`Enumerable.ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549211.aspx):

```
Dim allCalls As ILookup(Of String, String()) =
    (From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path)
     Order By line
     Let tokens = line.Split(","c)
     Where tokens.Length >= 6).
ToLookup(Function(p) p.tokens(1), Function(p) {p.tokens(2), p.tokens(5)})
```

One key can return zero, one or multiple values:

```
Dim calls = allCalls("Key")
For Each c As String In calls
    ' ... '
Next
```

Note that you don't get an  exception if the key doesn't exist. The seqeunce will be empty then.